# Remote Desktop to Virtual Machine

Tags: windows-server-2003, remote-desktop, virtualization

I recently reformatted one of my servers with Windows Server 2008 x64 and with that, installed the latest version of VMWare server on it.

Within that, I created a new Windows Server 2003 R2 x86 virtual machine for the purposes of being a backup domain controller.  I was able to successfully configure it as a domain controller and have it provide DNS service to my domain.  I've been using the VMWare remote console to set this up and figured it was time to get remote desktop working.

I set it up as I have with many other computers on my network (hitting the checkbox, making the firewall isn't blocking it) and I cannot get remote desktop to connect to it.  I've tried using the computer name and its IP address neither work.  I can ping the computer from the outside but the Virtual machine cannot ping anything from inside it.  All machines are on the same subnet.  I can't seem to figure this out.

Comment: Is there a reason that you're using VMWare Server still? It becomes EOS in June of this year.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do a scan of this system? Using something like nmap (available on windows) - find out if the port is actually open.

Also, under control panel, System, Remote tab - have you clicked Allow Remote Users, and then selected the domain based OU which actually has access?

This has got me on a number of times in the past :) Hope it helps

Comment: I have never used NMAP. However, I did add the domain administrator to the list of remote users and that allowed me to RD to it. I thought that was strange and unnecessary since in that box it said that account already could do it. I don't know why I had to explicitly put it in.  I still can't ping out from this machine.

Answer (score -1):

Try troubleshooting by making from the main PC telnet IP_ADDRESS 3389 where IP_ADDRESS is the IP address of the virtual machine. If you are able to connect the port is open on the virtual machine. From the virtual machine ping the IP address of the main machine. Are you using NAT or Bridge for the Ethernet adapter on the virtual machine?